# Toggle div after arriving from anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, anchor-scroll

My goal is to create anchor link with smooth scrolling to its destination and after it reaches it, toggle class to open accordion.

I have a hard time achieving a working result. Scroll code is here:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('.calendar a').click(function() {
$root.animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
});
```

I have no hash in my url.

How to include toggle in this scroll code?

Thanks!

Comment: "I  have no hash in my url"??? Please provide an example of your HTML to get help for questions like this :)

Comment: Sorry, this code actually produces hash to url. But its irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Without an example of what elements and classes are toggled, any example will include guesswork. Please do provide sample HTML.

Comment: That helps... which accordion is supposed to toggle?

Comment: Added update to match the requirement shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wait for the animate to complete using a jQuery `promise` and `always`. This works better than the animation callbacks (which do not fire if you are already at the final position)

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fb6yuf9k/1/

e.g.

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('.calendar a').click(function () {
    var $target = $($.attr(this, 'href'));
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    }, 500).promise().always(function(){
        $target.toggle();
    });
    return false;
});
```

For the specific website provided in comment, you want to toggle the element with `toggle-content` *beneath the target element*:

e.g.

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('.calendar a').click(function () {
    var $target = $($.attr(this, 'href'));
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    }, 500).promise().always(function(){
        $target.find('.toggle-content').toggle(); // or toggleClass etc
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an "completed" function callback you can stick at the end of the animation, like so:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('.calendar a').click(function() {
$root.animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 500, function() {
 //DO YOUR TOGGLE HERE
 $('#target').toggleClass('myClass')
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: In my browser it does (but your code is wrong with the CSS class in the fiddle). It fires always, but it fires twice. So the poster should probably use .removeClass

Comment: Why does your example fire `toggle` twice?

Comment: i know its my JS, but in your setup (of my code) the event does nothing visual. And the event always fires for me (but twice). FF 39.0.3

Comment: Twice in Chrome too. Mine only fires once (as it should), but trying to see why you get two events. Can you make your own JSFiddle?

Comment: people, dont upvote my answer, @TrueBlueAussie has the better one: only firing once